# Interop word processes not closing immediately

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, ms-word, office-interop

I am exporting word documents to PDFs using the interop word library in a multi-threaded WPF application and then convert them to PNGs using MagickNet library.

```
private void generateImagesFromOfficeDoc(Document currentDocument, CustomThread thread = null)
    {
        var token = tokenSource.Token;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApplication = null;

        string[] filePath = currentDocument.OriginalPath.Split('\\');
        currentDocument.Filename = filePath[filePath.Length - 1].Trim();

        string fileNameWithoutExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentDocument.Filename).Trim();
        string destinationPath;

        destinationPath = pngPath + "\\" + currentDocument.CreatedDate.Year.ToString() + "\\" + currentDocument.Specialty + "\\" + currentDocument.CreatedDate.Month + "\\" +
            currentDocument.CreatedDate.Day + "\\" + fileNameWithoutExtension;

        string pdfPath = magickNETTempDir + "\\" + fileNameWithoutExtension + ".pdf";
        string pdfName = fileNameWithoutExtension + ".pdf";
        string tempFile = magickNETTempDir + "\\" + currentDocument.Filename;

        try
        {
            // Copying the file from the original location to the temp folder. ** This is because impersonation have issues with the interop library.
            File.Copy(currentDocument.OriginalPath, tempFile);

            // Create the directory if it does not exist.
            if (!Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);
            }

            /************ CONVERTING THE DOCUMENT TO PDF ***************/
            wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            // Opening the word document
            var wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(tempFile);
            var pageCount = wordDocument.ComputeStatistics(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages, false);
            // Exporting the document to the PDF
            wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfPath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
            // Closing the document and the application.
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)wordDocument).Close(false);
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)wordApplication).Quit(false);
   }
```

Each thread opens up a word application and is supposed to close it after exporting the document. In the same method, I convert the exported PDF to PNG and then delete the temporary PDF (Code is excluded as I think it is not related to the issue).

The process does its work but since I am converting thousands of documents, I get quite a lot of word processes in the background eating up my RAM. The processes do close themselves eventually but it is very slow and thus I end up with more and more of the processes in the background. This does not happen on all machines and also not on every document so I am not sure what is going wrong.

Is there a way of closing them forcefully? I have tried the method of killing the processes by their name but that requires the application window to be visible which is something I don't want.

Comment: Have you tried running this code in separate application domain & unloading the domain when you're done ?

Comment: Have you tried creating `Word.Application` once and using that for all of your `Document.Open` calls?  I have used Word in the past for its spell checking library and I've seen that it will stay open for an amount of time following a call to `Close/Quit`.

Comment: Why can't you use one instance of the Interop?  If you're trying to multithread this, the problem is that there is probably only 1 IO thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run into similar problems when using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` dll. I found out that I had to release all of the COM objects that I had been using before `Excel` would disappear from the Windows Task Manager Processes tab. To be clear, I'd close the application, but its process would remain visible in the Task Manager until I released the COM objects. Try something like this:

```
private void ReleaseComObjects(bool isQuitting)
{
    try
    {
        if (isQuitting)
        {
            workbook.Close(false, missing, missing); 
            excelApplication.Quit();
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
        if (worksheets != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheets);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApplication);
        workbook = null;
        worksheets = null;
        worksheet = null;
        excelApplication = null;
    }
    catch { }
    finally { GC.Collect(); }
}

private void ReleaseComObjects()
{
    ReleaseComObjects(false);
}
```

Comment: Works as expected. It slows down the application a bit but I am happy to sacrifice a little bit of speed for reliability in this case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't see how releasing `COM` objects would slow anything down, but I'm glad you fixed your problem.

Comment: It seems my tasks are running synchronously now since that fix. I use 4 tasks and all 4 use a different word process but only one at a time converts the doc to pdf and then the 2nd task will do the same thing and then the third and the fourth. I rolled back to the version before this and they all work at the same time asynchronously. So in a way, I have lost the multi-threading, not sure why.

Comment: Wow, that's an unfortunate trade off. I can't tell you why that's happening, but if you ask another question, perhaps linking to this one, someone else might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks. I might have to ask another question then, but I also realised that releasing the word document object by `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordDocument)` takes like 15-20 seconds which doesn't seem right.

Comment: That does sound strange... mine only takes a split second.

Comment: [Here](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/317109/en-us) is a Microsoft Knowledge Base article with an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordDocument) takes like 15-20 seconds in web application